# Difference in Exception handling py code in Odoo 11

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

What are differences in exception from the coding point of view in Odoo 11 as compared in Odoo 10? Can't find other differences except
**except Exception, e:** to **except Exception as e:**
My code shows error somehow from exception while converting a module from Odoo 10 to Odoo 11.

Comment: The exception handling is related to the Python version you are using - Odoo 11 [supports Python 3 only](https://www.odoo.com/groups/community-59/community-32859400) and in Python 3 [only `except Exception as e:` is supported](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/). Could you post the code snippet/error you are getting for us to be able to help you better (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.5 and earlier versions, 'as' isn't supported, so you use **except Exception, e:**

In Python 2.6+ versions, **both** can be used.

But from Python 3.x, **except Exception *as* e is required** to assign an exception to a variable.